# Can't create div layout with xsl conditional statement

Tags: xslt, if-statement

I'm trying to create some  and  based on the position() value in a foreach loop with something like this:

```
<xsl:for-each >

  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="number(position())=1">
      <div>
    </xsl:when>
  </xsl:choose>

  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="number(position())=last()">
      </div>
    </xsl:when>
  </xsl:choose>

</xsl:for-each>
```

I have tried with if statement first. If I use text instead of  => no pb
Both condition are true (tested with text)

I miss something but what? I think the pb may come with the fact that xsl processor test the validity of the HTML on each loop.

Comment: An XSLT stylesheet file must itself be well-formed XML with properly nested tags.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it is not working in this way AFAIK. But you could reverse it and make something like this:

```
<div>
    <xsl:for-each select="something">
        <!-- do something -->
    </xsl:for-each>
</div>
```

Comment: In fact I have understand where the problem come => Xsl need to open and close tag in the same condition so I need to have the <div> blabla </div> in the same if statement.

Some ppl use this trick 

    `<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;div&gt;</xsl:text>`

But it not pretty so I will create a nice nested structure.

thks all